# Get Azure Automation Runbook Credential in Python

Tags: python, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity, azure-runbook

I'm trying to get an Automation Account credential in my Python 3.8 runbook using a managed identity.

The current code looks like this.

```
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.mgmt.automation import AutomationClient 
from azure.mgmt.automation.operations import CredentialOperations 

def get_credential(credential):

    subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    automation_account = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

    # Create Managed Identity object
    auth_client = ManagedIdentityCredential()

    # Create Automation Client
    client = AutomationClient(auth_client, subscription_id)

    # Create Credential Operations Client
    credential_client = CredentialOperations(client._client, client._config, client._serialize, client._deserialize)

    # Get Credential
    cred = credential_client.get(subscription_id, automation_account, credential)

return cred
```

The code gets the credential, but the problem I noticed is that this code only gets the credential object, which doesn't include the actual password that I'm looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-automation/azure.mgmt.automation.operations.credentialoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-automation-operations-credentialoperations-get

I've tried to find another way of getting the actual password, but haven't yet managed to find one.

Anyone know?

Comment: The password is for a non Microsoft service that doesn't support managed identity.

Comment: @ChristofferL have you tried using automationassets.get_automation_credential ?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Is it this one? [link](https://github.com/azureautomation/python_emulated_assets/blob/master/automationassets/automationassets.py) - I've looked it, but it seems to be used to emulate the credential/variable service within an automation account when developing locally.

Comment: @ChristofferL I believe you can't fetch the password. Even by using this Rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/credential/get?view=rest-automation-2023-11-01&tabs=HTTP, you can get the username

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin It would be unfortunate if true. It is possible in Powershell with [Get-AutomationPSCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials?tabs=azure-powershell#textual-runbook-example). There are examples for Python, but those refers to the module that you said before.

Comment: Yes, its feasible in Powershell.

Comment: @ChristofferL I am able to get the password using [this](https://i.imgur.com/WURlc8K.png) code

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin How/where from did you install the automationasset module?

Comment: @ChristofferL I have created [here](https://i.imgur.com/dNrL49e.png) but you can also create it in vs code using Automation extension

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Yeah, that actually works. I was thrown off by the automationasset file I linked to before. Thanks for the help! If you want to post a reply I will add that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the below code in Azure Automation Runbook to get the credentials.

```py
import automationassets
from automationassets import AutomationAssetNotFound

# get a credential
cred = automationassets.get_automation_credential("{credential_name}")
print (cred["username"])
print (cred["password"])
```

***Output***-

[image]

You can also use this code in vs code by adding Azure Automation extension in it.

***References***-

[Manage credentials in Azure Automation | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials?tabs=python3#textual-runbook-example).

Comment: Does not work on a Hybrid Worker